# Vanilla JS menu dropdown wont close

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

When I click on the fa-bars to open the show the #navbar  it will show up

but when I click on the menu again it will not close the menu. not sure what

I'm doing wrong? I tried using event target but that didn't work either. do I

need to make another class to active class to see if it works?

```js
const navbar = document.querySelector('#navbar');
const menuBars = document.querySelector('.fa-bars');

menuBars.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
if(navbar ==='block'){
    navbar.style.display='none';
}
else{
    navbar.style.display='block';
}
});
```

```css
.icon-nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.fa-bars{
    color: #3099b4;
    font-size: 28px;
}
.fa-bars:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #4f5052;
    transition: all .4s ease-in;
}
/* navbar on drop down */
#navbar{
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 40vh;
    
}
.links{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 38px;
}
.links a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:#3099b4;
    padding: 5px;
}
.links a:hover{
    color: #cee3d9;
    transition: all .4s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-nav">
  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
 </div>
<header id="navbar">
  <div class="links">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About Me</a>
    <a href="#project">Projects</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contacts</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow community. For a first timer, you asked your question pretty well. Please don't forget to mark the answer that helped you as correct. This will help others who find your question or have this same problem know what will work for them. All the best @MichaelFazekas Cheers!

Comment: Based on what you've provided, I suspect the problem has to do with the "if(navbar === 'block')" check which maybe should be "if(navbar.style.display === 'block')". In the future, please be sure to provide the complete context to your problem and a better initial description - have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. For example: the HTML snippet here is incomplete, and you sound like you're using Font Awesome but didn't say so, and its also not clear where your page actually runs that javascript. I hope I've been helpful and that you find the help you need. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
if(navbar.style.display ==='block'){ //Here you need to check display style
  navbar.style.display='none';
}
else {
  navbar.style.display='block';
}
```

Just change if condition, you are checking just element, but you need to check style for that element to make it display none. I edited the condtion

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the `navbar.style.display ==='block'` that would solve your issue.

But i would solve this issue using css class. Here you can check my approach. I've added an `active` class to show or hide the menu.

Here i've toggled the `active` class using js.

```
menuBars.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  navbar.classList.toggle('active')
});
```

And here is the extra css

```
#navbar.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```js
const navbar = document.querySelector('#navbar');
const menuBars = document.querySelector('.fa-bars');

menuBars.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  navbar.classList.toggle('active')
});
```

```css
.icon-nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.fa-bars{
    color: #3099b4;
    font-size: 28px;
}
.fa-bars:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #4f5052;
    transition: all .4s ease-in;
}
/* navbar on drop down */
#navbar{
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 40vh;
}



#navbar.active {
  display: block;
}

.links{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 38px;
}
.links a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color:#3099b4;
    padding: 5px;
}
.links a:hover{
    color: #cee3d9;
    transition: all .4s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
  <div class="icon-nav">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
  <header id="navbar">
    <div class="links">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="#about">About Me</a>
      <a href="#project">Projects</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contacts</a>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```